# Postgres COPY command opimization questions

Tags: postgresql, indexing, copy

When using the COPY command, the docs state that it is optimized for bulk data loads. What does this optimization cost? Does it bypass indexing? Does it bypass replication? Triggers?

EX: If I were to use COPY to insert data from multiple files into the same table, and if I need to leave the indexes intact, should I re-index the table after all COPY operations are done?

Answer (score 0):

From the [fine manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

> COPY FROM will invoke any triggers and check constraints on the
>   destination table. However, it will not invoke rules.

You don't need to reindex after a COPY FROM, but it's probably a good idea to update statistics. (`analyze table_name...`)